# Is there a tool to spy out messages sent to a window

Tags: windows, message

Is there a tool that shows messages sent to a specific window? I've heard that WinSpector should do it, but the site seems to be offline.

Best regards,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spy++ (with Visual Studio 6) does the job quite nicely.

You can download Managed [Spy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx) here